# calc: fill multiple adjacent rows with a formula?

Tags: org-table, calc

With Table>Set Field>Formula, I'm able to do what I want for a particular field, in this case that corresponding to Aug 07. How can I fill multiple adjacent fields in one go, say Aug 7-15?

```
#+TITLE: Ledger
#+CONSTANT: r=10


| Date                 | Owed |
|----------------------+------|
| [2022-08-06 Sat]     |   10 |
| [2022-08-06 Sat] + d |   20 |
#+TBLFM: @3$1=@2$1+1d::@3$2=@2$2+10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following table/formula should do what you want IIUC:

```org
| Date             | Owed |
|------------------+------|
| [2022-08-06 Sat] |   10 |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
|                  |      |
#+TBLFM: @3$1..@>$1=@-1$1+1::@3$2..@>$2=@-1$2+10
```

You need to have enough rows for what you want: the formula will fill however many you actually have.

The formula reads: row 3 to the last row, column 1: use the date from the entry above the current row and the first column(`@-1$1`), and add one day to it. The second part is similar but it adds 10 to the entry from the previous row and the second column.

Note that I did not use the `d`: `calc` then calculates dates properly.
You might also find `S-RET` useful when filling in tables with dates: you get the first date in and then keep pressing `S-RET` for each next day, however many times you wish.

Relevant sections of the manual:

[References](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) - see particularly the `Range references` subsection.

[Field references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) in the same section as above but in the `Field references` subsection describes relative references like `@-1`.

[Built-in Table Editor](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html) - see the `Calculations` subsection for `S-RET`.

**EDIT**: There are *two* formulas on the `#+TBLFM:` line: the first one, `@3$1..@>$1=@-1$1+1`, fills in the first column as indicated by its range: third to last row, first column; the second, `@3$2..@>$2=@-1$2+10`, fills in the second column: its range is third to last row, second column. You can also write formulas for rectangular ranges consisting of multiple rows and columns, e.g. `@2$1..@>$> = 0` would initialize a table to `0` (we leave the first row alone, assuming it contains headers).

To evaluate the formulas, just `C-c C-c` on the `#+TBLFM:` line.

Note that in order for the formula to work the way you want, you must have enough empty rows for your criteria (e.g. to fill in from Aug 6 to Aug 15, you must have 10 rows in the body of the table), but instead of counting, I prefer to create the table with more rows than necessary and trim off the excess after the formula has been applied.

If you want a hybrid approach where you use `S-RET` for the first column to manually create it and then use a formula for the second column, just keep the second formula in the `#TBLFM:` line:

```org
| Date             | Owed |
|------------------+------|
| [2022-08-06 Sat] |   10 |
| [2022-08-07 Sun] |      |
| [2022-08-08 Mon] |      |
| [2022-08-09 Tue] |      |
| [2022-08-10 Wed] |      |
| [2022-08-11 Thu] |      |
| [2022-08-12 Fri] |      |
| [2022-08-13 Sat] |      |
| [2022-08-14 Sun] |      |
| [2022-08-15 Mon] |      |
#+TBLFM: @3$2..@>$2=@-1$2+10
```

`C-c C-c` on the `#+TBLFM:` line will leave the first column untouched and fill in the second column.

Comment: If I do S-RET under Owed in the second row, I get $11 instead of $20...

Comment: That' correct: the default increment is `1`. That works well with the dates (if you want to increment by days), but it doesn't work with other increments. You can set the value of `org-table-copy-increment` to `10` before you do the second column, but it's easier to use the formula. But I often set it to `7` before doing `S-RET` on a dates column, if I want to increment by weeks, rather than by days. Note that in a non-numeric, non-date column, `S-RET` copies down the previous entry, so it's a quick way to fill in a text column where the entries are constant for longish stretches.

Comment: The formula you created is supposed to increment rows in the second column by $10, right? How do I fill the rows using this formula?

Comment: Edited the answer to add some more info: HTH.